Assignment of variable of type object makes a copy, not by reference?
So I thought I understood how value and type variables work in C# but I encountered a case that's not clear or intuitive to me. If I have a class instance of type "Assembly" (System.Reflection.Assembly) and assign it to another variable, then it seems to be "Copied" rather than by reference:
var assembly2= assembly1;
assembly1= LoadOtherAssembly();


Console.WriteLine(assembly2);
Console.WriteLine(assembly1);

I obviously get a different assembly (whatever LoadOtherAssembly() gives me) on the second line (assembly1), but "assembly2" seems to have the original Assembly inside.
Whenever I do this with any other class this doesn't happen (as expected):
public class Person
{
   public string Name;
}

var dave=new Person();
dave.Name="Dave";
var culley=dave;

culley.Name="Culley";

Console.WriteLine(dave.Name);
Console.WriteLine(culley.Name);


In this case both spit out "Culley", as expected. What am I missing, and how is this different to the first case, using "Assembly"?

"but "otherAssembly" seems to have the original Assembly inside." of course it does - you have not changed what otherAssembly references. Are you expecting otherAssembly to always point to the same instance that originalAssembly does, even if you change which object originalAssembly references?

When you called LoadOtherAssembly(); you created another object, different from the first one.  Not the case with your Person example; both variables point to the same object.

You did not do the same with the other class. Look closely at the order of assignments. There is no magic here.

Yo got wrong idea how it works. And your example does not depend whether the variable holds reference or value type.
// here int1 has its initial value, let's say 0
var int2 = int1; // Here we assign 0 to int2 
int1 = GetOtherInteger(); // Here we change int1 and it does not have value of 0 anymore, while int2 is still 0

Now you can similairly think of your example:
// Here assembly1 has some reference to object o#1

// Here assembly2 hold reference (pointing to o#1)
var assembly2 = assembly1;

// Here assembly1 will get new reference to new object o#2,
// so it will change, but assembly2 will be unaffected,
// as it still holds reference r#1
assembly1 = LoadOtherAssembly();

Console.WriteLine(assembly2);
Console.WriteLine(assembly1);

To observe "mutability" of reference types, let me present you other, more representative example:
public class MyDto 
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

var dto1 = new MyDto() { Value = 42 };
var dto2 = dto1;

// Now both dto1 and dto2 hold reference to created object (two references pointing to the same object)

// Now change value in one object,
dto1.Value = 1000;

// and observe change in other variable.
Console.WriteLine(dto2.Value); // it will print 1000 !

